# Java loading class from bytes doesn't work correctly

Tags: java, classloader

I'm trying to load a class at runtime from a byte array.
It works fine, the custom class loader returns a valid class object with the correct name. I can use the class object and I can use the class via reflection.

My problem is, if I try to use the class directly it is still throwing a `ClassNotFoundException`. So my question is, how to load a class that I can direct use it?

The custom `ClassLoader` will be about loading library's, so I directly refer to the classes

My code:

```
public class ByteClassLoader extends ClassLoader {

    private final HashMap<String, byte[]> classBytes;

    public ByteClassLoader(final ClassLoader loader, HashMap<String, byte[]> classes) {
        super(loader);
        classBytes = classes;
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?> findClass(String name) throws ClassNotFoundException {
        final byte[] arr = classBytes.remove(name);

        if (arr != null)
            return defineClass(name, arr, 0, arr.length);

        return super.findClass(name);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        final HashMap<String, byte[]> map = new HashMap<>();

        // Load class file
        final byte[] data = Files.readAllBytes(
            new File("/Users/Florian/Desktop/AC.class").toPath()
        );

        map.put("dyn.AC", data);

        // Create new Custom classloader
        final ByteClassLoader loader = new ByteClassLoader(
            Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader(), map
        );

        // Set context class loader
        Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(loader);

        // Loading the class
        Class<?> acc = loader.findClass("dyn.AC");

        // Works. -_-
        acc.getMethod("trigger").invoke(null);

        // Works
        System.out.println(acc.getName());

        // Test method, only contains System.out method, DOESNT WORK
        AC.trigger();
    }
}
```

Content of AC: http://paste.reflex.rip/umecoruwer.cs

Stacktrace: http://paste.reflex.rip/exezividuz.swift

Comment: Can you provide the dyn.AC class here.  Is the dyn.AC class in your class path? Does it implement Serializable ?

Comment: @JerinJoseph The AC class only contains the static method trigger, this method contains a System.out message, that's it. The AC class doesn't implement/extend anything. It's just a normal class

Comment: please add the content of `AC` in your question

Comment: and also the stacktrace

Comment: You probably have *two* AC classes loaded, or you compiled with AC on the classpath and then run without AC on the classpath. You need to be aware that the class obtained from your custom classloader is not available for resolving the VM's class dependencies and that AC loaded by different class loaders is not the same class.

Comment: @Durandal The class isn't available before I'm trying to load it. I tested it using Class.forName(); Also, I replaced loadClass with Class.forName() because of fancyness. ^^

Comment: @NicolasFilotto Edited it into the post!

Comment: I can confirm that this actually works. I only changed paths and dny.AC to AC.

Comment: @Jacob Are you sure that you're loading the AC class at runtime and not before? ._.

Comment: You haven't understood my 2nd sentence then. You *cannot* refer to AC from your code by normal type reference. Its a natural consequence of how you're loading the class.

Comment: @Durandal I saw some other programs doing this, so there need to be a way to do this. How can I do this? ._. If I would know what's the default classloader I could inject the classes vector and put my loaded class in it. That might work

Comment: What exactly have you seen other programs "do"? I'm sure you're missing a crucial detail, like an interface the class needs to implement to be usable.

Comment: @Durandal They are loading libraries at runtime and use them. So, I got a little idea. I read a bit in the Class.forName code and I saw it is using the class loader of the caller class for default. So what if I restart my own plugin a the custom class loader? :o

Comment: Load "libraries" at runtime? The term *library* is meaningless - no such thing exists in java language (only in the users minds). Nebulous terminology only makes things harder to explain and understand, avoid that. Come clean what kind of actual problem you're trying to solve, then maybe someone can help you. The way you are trying creates a needless egg/hen paradox - for no practical benefit.

Comment: @Durandal I've a library which is dynamiclly changing before it get loaded. So I can't load it before I start the program, because the changes only can be done when the program is already running. So I need to load it at runtime. Btw, I found a hacky way to load the class into the correct classloader. The default class loader is an url class loader. I've injected the URLClassPath and I returned a fake resource object which redirects to my class. It work! :o